# How to fix issues with NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/R$string on Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, noclassdeffounderror

Recently, I faced an issue that I'm not able to solve for a week, reading different sources with advices. But, nothing helped.

So, the issues is in **NoClassDefFoundError** that appeared after upgrading:

1. Gradle Wrapper from 5.x to 6.x
2. Gradle Build Tool
3. Firebase dependencies (which are actually brings these classes I have problems with)

What I have already tried to fix an issue:

1. Tried to downgrade Firbase libraries (I have only core, ads and analytic)
2. Tried to disable transitive **basemenet** dependency
3. Tried to apply **BOM** to sync dependencies
4. Tried to upgrade/downgrade android build plugin
5. Tried to find issue with existing green-dao version, but it looks good

Here are dependencies from my **build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {

    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timberVersion"

    //Reactive
    implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxjava', version: rxJavaVersion
    implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxandroid', version: androidRxJavaVersion

    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$androidFirebaseBomVersion")

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'

    // Android lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$androidLifeCycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$androidLifeCycleVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$androidLifeCycleVersion"

    // Android support
    //TODO once can be replaced with com.google.android.material
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$androidMaterialVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidAppCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$androidSupportConstraintLayoutVersion"

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpVersion"

    // Dependency injection (Dagger)
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"

    // Database
    implementation "org.sqldroid:sqldroid:$sqlDroidVersion"
    implementation "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:$flywayVersion"

    // UI
    implementation "com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:$materialDialogsVersion"
    implementation "com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:$androidRateVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.nex3z:flow-layout:$flowLayoutVersion"

    // Utils
    implementation "com.annimon:stream:$streamVersion"
    implementation "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:$findBugsVersion"
    implementation "net.objecthunter:exp4j:$exp4jVersion"

    // Checkout
    implementation "org.solovyev.android:checkout:$checkoutVersion"

    /**
     * Test dependencies
     */
    // Unit tests
    testImplementation group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: hamcrestAllVersion
    testImplementation("junit:junit:$junitVersion") {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: mockitoVersion
    testImplementation('androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0') {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-annotations"
    }
    testImplementation 'net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0'

    // Integration tests
    androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"

    // Espresso dependencies
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espressoVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:$jsr305Version"

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$testRunnerVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:$testRunnerVersion"
    androidTestUtil "androidx.test:orchestrator:$testOrchestratorVersion"

    androidTestImplementation "commons-io:commons-io:$commonsIOVersion"
    androidTestImplementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: guavaVersion

    // Spoon
    androidTestImplementation "com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:$spoonClientVersion"
}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/R$string;                                                                                                                                                                                                            
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.StringResourceValueReader.<init>(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(FirebaseOptions.java:156)                                        
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:244)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1759)                                             
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1734)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)                        
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6420)                                              
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6012)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5951)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.R$string" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myestimates.buildercalcfree-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myestimates.buildercalcfree-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]  
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)                                            
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)                                                             
09-15 11:07:13.467  1129  1129 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 18 more
```

Maybe this is something common issue, but I have no idea how to deal with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after few days of digging around I have found a solution. So, to make it work I had to:

1. Downgrade **Android Gradle Plugin** to 3.5.3 version
2. Downgrade **Gordon** plugin to 1.0.6 version
3. Migrated **fabric-crashlytic** to **firebase-crashlytic**. With adding plugin of the last as well, otherwise, errors occur.

All other updates could be set, but this 3 items have to be sticked to the versions mentioned.

Comment: You saved my day! it is currently the only working solution, but there are no words.