# After upgrade to android 31 get error " Failed resolution of: Landroidx/startup"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My project is with multiple sub-modules.

[image]

after upgrading it to android 31, I m getting "AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/startup/R$string;" error.

I tried with many ways to solve this, but no results yet. Please help me.

adding stacktrace

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

2022-12-06 11:31:54.377  4537-4537  AndroidRuntime          pid-4537                             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.easypay.ican, PID: 4537
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/startup/R$string;
at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:216)
at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:206)
at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:45)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2404)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2374)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7422)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6939)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6710)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.startup.R$string" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~zsypRkw3OTJxLIDeKKQKdQ==/com.easypay.ican-LRtgK_OiOc4mTtKIqazSwA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~zsypRkw3OTJxLIDeKKQKdQ==/com.easypay.ican-LRtgK_OiOc4mTtKIqazSwA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~zsypRkw3OTJxLIDeKKQKdQ==/com.easypay.ican-LRtgK_OiOc4mTtKIqazSwA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:216) 
at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:206) 
at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:45) 
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2404) 
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2374) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7422) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6939) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6710) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
2022-12-06 11:31:54.381  4537-4537  CustomActivityOnCrash   pid-4537                             E  App has crashed, executing CustomActivityOnCrash's UncaughtExceptionHandler
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/startup/R$string;

Comment: Please add the entire stack trace as text...

Comment: @PavelB. as your request added the error log.  Thanks for looking this..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63898832/how-to-fix-issues-with-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lcom-google-a  try downgrading build tools